# mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack While using Login through FBConnect

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

When I am running my App on Device I am getting the following error and app crashes
After using Login through FBConnect

> > mi_cmd_stack_list_frames: Not enough frames in stack.

I am not getting any appropriate solution for this.

I sent a Testflight build to cleint he is also getting the crash at same place

Comment: I think you are not using ARC and managing memory by own and you are trying to Over-releasing any objects. Try to find it.

Comment: I find out I am getting this crash when I am trying to Login through FBConnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Problem with Facebook SDK 3.0 Now I have updated my Facebook SDK to 3.1.1 from [GitHUb](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) Now its working good